# How to get the RTC time in python Windows OS

Tags: python, python-3.x, time

Currently making use of datetime.datetime.now() from python code to obtain the date/time stamp. However this is the date/timezone that is set on the system which can be changed/altered.
How can i retrieve the real time i.e RTC time from python. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you use "python-3.7"? If so: do you know about [time.monotonic_ns](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.monotonic_ns)? It must work on Windows too

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Linux/Unix, you can get the system-wide real time clock with the [time](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.clock_gettime) module from the standard library, as follows:

```
import time
rtc = time.clock_gettime(time.CLOCK_REALTIME)
print("System RTC = {rtc}")

> System RTC = 1549619678.899073
```

For Windows, RTC is not available. There are a variety of other clocks you could use, depending on your application, which wouldn't be affected by updates to system time. For instance, if you are trying to measure time between two separate calls, and don't want this to be affected by changes to system datetime/timezone, you can use [time.monotonic()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.monotonic) which is available on Windows as well. However, is only useful relative to another call to `time.monotonic()` (i.e. for measuring duration) and does not have a defined reference point, so you can't do a call to `time.monotonic()` to ask "what time is it?"

Comment: @taylor Is that applicable to Windows operating system ? Looks to supported for Unix, but how can RTC be obtained for Windows OS ?

Comment: @Sudeep You are correct. [Documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.clock_gettime) states "Availability: Unix"

Comment: Apologies - the original question didn't specify OS. I've updated to include Windows